# SpringBoot error with default h2 version

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I am not able to run a spring boot app when using h2 without specifying the h2 version.
I get the error:

> Description:
>
> Cannot determine embedded database driver class for
>   database type NONE
>
> Action:
>
> If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the
>   classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a
>   particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are
>   currently active).

Configuration looks like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

But if I specify the older version explicitly like:

```
<version>1.3.156</version>
```

then the app starts just fine. The only thing is, now I get the warning in the pom.xml file that says : "Overriding managed version 1.4.192 for h2".

Is this a known issue of spring boot / maven ?
Should I worry about this ?
Is there a known solution for this issue ?

P.S.
I'm on windows 10

Here's my POM file

```
<groupId>com.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>das-boot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <name>das-boot</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.156</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Would help to see the full pom.xml that you are working with.

Comment: Added, it has the contents as show in the video guide - the only difference is that I had to add explicit version for the h2.

Comment: There will be dependencies in the Spring Bill Of Materials on h2 - so your likely creating a dependency issue with the older version. Optiosn are to check the older BOM's to find a older Spring boot with support for your h2